# Displaying data with ngFor in Angular properly

Tags: html, angular, ngxs

I am trying to display some data I receive from my endpoint. Printing it to the console log works fine, but I am unable to display it on the HTML page i.e. the page is blank. I have tried with

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let animal of animals | async">
                {{ animal }} 
        </li>
</ul>
```

This is how I have set up my component:

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  animals : Animals [];

  constructor(private store: Store) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(fetchUsers).subscribe(animals => {
      this.animals  = animals ;
      console.log(this.animals );
    });
  }

}
```

In the console I am getting the JSON, which I am receiving from my endpoint:

```
animals :
 animals : Array(1)
  0: {id: "1562", animalType: "dog"}
```

I expect it to return the animal object, but later I am going to let it print the `animalType`

Comment: in your HTML you either type `{{ animal | json }}` or `{{ animal.animalType }}`

Comment: It is still blank :/

Comment: Looks like there's an extra `animals` top level property. Please edit your question with the JSON representation of the result of your API call.

Comment: use `<li *ngFor="let animal of animals">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the async operator because you are not using a promise or observable for the property animals, so all you need is a reference to it. You also need to add some kind of protection for when your array isn't initalized yet. I used ngIf for that:

```
<ul *ngIf="animals">
        <li *ngFor="let animal of animals">
                {{ animal.animalType }} 
        </li>
</ul>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Then in your component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(fetchUsers).subscribe(animals => {
      this.animals  = animals.animals ; // looks like you need to work on this
      console.log(this.animals );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, there was a top level

Answer (score 0):

animals is not an observable, why are you using async??
tru this:

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let animal of animals">
                {{ animal }} 
        </li>
</ul>
```